# Error in IdMessageClient.pas in RAD XE7

Tags: indy

In `IdMessageClient.pas` there is an error, which causes crash during reading messages.

If a messages encoding is 'quoted-printable' then an attachment is not read properly and an empty exception is called.

Please modify procedure TIdMessageClient.ReceiveBody, line 968 from:

```
if PosInStrArray(LContentTransferEncoding, ['7bit', '8bit', 'binary'], False) = -1 then begin {do not localize}
```

to

```
if PosInStrArray(LContentTransferEncoding, ['7bit', 'quoted-printable', '8bit', 'binary'], False) = -1 then begin {do not localize}
```

Maybe it is required to add 'quoted-printable' clause in other places - I do not know.

Problem appeared in RAD XE7. In previous version all was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First - that particular line of code has never appeared on line 968 of `IdMessageClient.pas`. Depending on which SVN revision you are looking at in the past year, it appears on line 967, 970, or 946 instead.

Second - the SVN revision that shipped with XE7 (5177) is not the latest revision that is currently available (5269, at the time of this writing).  Make sure you are using the latest revision, as `ReceiveBody()` has already received several updates since XE7's release.

Third - if you are using an up-to-date revision, and are still encountering an email that fails to parse, please provide the actual email for review.

Fourth - even then, I am not inclined to add `quoted-printable` to that particular `if` statement, as it does not belong there.  That particular `if` statement is looking for *valid* `Content-Transfer-Encoding` values for `multipart/...` types, and `quoted-printable` is strictly forbidden by RFC 2045 Section 6.4 (and is stated as much in comments above that line of code).  If you have an email that is using an illegal `Content-Transfer-Encoding` then the email is malformed, and I don't like making Indy parse blatantly-malformed data unless absolutely necessary.  We have already encountered malformed emails that use `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` *without* actually QP-encoding the body text, so `quoted-printable` gets ignored in that scenario.  If your failing email is actually (but illegally) QP-encoding the body text of `multipart/...` types, you may have to disable Indy's decoder and decode the email yourself.